# Allow users to remove their account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, account-management

I am developing a gallery which allows users to post photos, comments, vote and do many other tasks.

Now I think that it is correct to allow users to unsubscribe and remove all their data if they want to. However it is difficult to allow such a thing because you run the risk to break your application (e.g. what should I do when a comment has many replies? what should I do with pages that have many revisions by different users?).

Photos can be easily removed, but for other data (i.e. comments, revisions...) I thought that there are three possibilities:

- assign it to the admin
- assign it to a user called "removed-user"
- mantain the current associations (i.e. the user ID) and only rename user's data (e.g. assign  a new username such as "removed-user-24" and a non-existent e-mail such as "noreply-removed-user-24@mysite.com"

What are the best practices to follow when we allow users to remove their accounts? How do you implement them (particularly in Rails)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally in a system you would not want to "hard delete" data. The best way I know of and that we have implemented in past is "soft delete". Maintain a status column in all your data tables which ideally refers to the fact whether the row is active or not. Any row when created is "Active" by default; however as entries are deleted; they are made inactive.

All select queries which display data on screen filter results for only "active records". This way you get following advantages:
1. Data Recovery is possible.
2. You can have a scheduled task on database level, which can take care of hard deletes of once in a way; if really needed. (Like a SQL procedure or something)
3. You can have an admin screen to be able to decide which accounts, entries etc you'd really want to mark for deletion
4. A temperory disabling of account can also be implemented with same solution.

In prod environments where I have worked on, a hard delete is a strict No-No. Infact audits are maintained for deletes also. But if application is really small; it'd be upto user.

I would still suggest a "virtual delete" or a "soft delete" with periodic cleanup on db level; which will be faster efficient and optimized way of cleaning up.

Comment: What about privacy? The user may complain that you haven't deleted his name, his e-mail, etc. (even if anyone will never see that informations). Do you think I shouldn't care about this? (I know I am too precise ;) )

Comment: I know that scenario will occur; however here are few things.
1. User would primarily care that data is never shown again to any user and is not used in any way; which anyway won't be because it would be dormant, inactive and unsusable as it won't be displayed anywhere on screen. Do you think Gmail hard deletes your email? No they don't do; there is always an inactive copy which has been used in court rulings several times.
2. In case you do want to delete the data actually, I already suggested a hard delete PL/SQL procedure which can take care of it in more efficient and capable manner.

Comment: You can run that procedure on a periodic basis without putting any immediate load on system. Such procedures or scripts are good for less traffic hours.

Answer (score 5):

I've typically solved this type of problem by having an active flag on user, and simply setting active to false when the user is deleted.  That way I maintain referential integrity throughout the system even if a user is "deleted".  In the business layer I always validate a user is active before allowing them to perform operations.  I also filter inactive users when retrieving data.

Comment: Yes, this is a simple approach. But.. what about privacy? The user may complain that you haven't deleted his name, his e-mail, etc. (even if anyone will never see that informations).

Comment: You can certainly remove the email and all contact information.  The references are what is important.  Also, if you do it right, the data will be completely hidden from any outside view.

Comment: also if you remove all specific data from the user and still want to keep some of the content the user has posted you could use a simple getter method to render "deleted user" and still show the content (if that is ok with your TOS)

Comment: btw. restful_authentication comes with some handy methods to archieve this behavior. Just use a statefull authentication model and set the state to deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The usual thing to do is instead of deleting them from a database, add a boolean flag field and have it be true for valid users and false for invalid users.  You will have to add code to filter on the flag. You should also remove all relevant data from the user that you can.  The primary purpose of this flag is to keep the links intact.  It is a variant of the renaming the user's data, but the flag will be easier to check.

Comment: Good idea! Do you think that username must be deleted?

Comment: That depends on how they are used.  If they are displayed you may want to turn it into something so that the user doesn't feel that their data is still visible (although this can be done when displaying as well).  If usernames are unique you will have to take care about changing them to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I generally don't like to delete anything and instead opt to mark records as deleted/unpublished using states (with AASM i.e. acts as state machine).

I prefer states and events to just using flags as you can use events to update attributes and send emails etc. in one foul swoop. Then check states to decide what to do later on.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting in a delete date field that contains the date/time the user unsubscribed - not only to the user record, but to all information related to that user.  The app should check the field prior to displaying anything.  You can then run a hard delete for all records 30 days (your choice of time) after the delete date. This will allow the information not to be shown (you will probably need to update the app in a few places), time to allow the user to re-subscribe (accidental or rethinking) and a scheduled process to delete old data.  I would remove ALL information about the member and any related comments about the member or their prior published data (photos, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it changing lot since update with Data Protection and GDPR, etc.

the reason I found this page as I was looking for advice because of new Apply policy on account deletion requirements extended https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=i71db0mv

We are using Ruby on Rails right now. Your answers seem a little outdated? or not or still useful right now

I was thinking something like that

create a new table  “`old_user_table`” with old user_id , First name, Second name, email, and booking slug.

It will allow keep all users who did previous booking. And deleted their user ID in the app. We need to keep all records for booking for audit purpose in the last 5 years in the app.

the user setup with this app, the user but never booking, then the user will not transfer to “`old_user_table`” cos the user never booking.

Does it make sense? something like that?